# Finding nCk that can have huge values of n and k

Tags: algorithm, modulus

Firstly this is not my homework ..I am stuck on a question during my practice.

I want to compute the value of this expression:
ans=(2^huge)%p..

where:

huge=n1Ck1+ n2Ck2 +n3Ck3 ..... [n1,n2.. can be as large as 10^4 and k1,k2.. are less than 10]

p=a prime number less than 2^32

I know how to find out (a^b)%p using fast [right to left binary method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) , but my problem is how to find the combination [nCk]  of a numbers like 10000C9 that can result in such a huge number and then later use that in the modular exponentiation method ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast n choose k mod p for large n?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118137/fast-n-choose-k-mod-p-for-large-n)

Comment: But can I then use the remainder value (suppose r) in (2^r)%p??Will it be correct??

Comment: Do you want to calculate `x ^ C(n,k) % p` for some `x`? In that case, you don't need `C(n,k) % p` but `C(n,k) % (p-1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `2^(p-1)==1 mod p`, you can do all the calculations of the exponents modulo `p-1`.

Comment: In the case p == 2 then a is either 0 or 1 mod 2. If a = 0 then the answer is 0. If a = 1 then we only need to know if huge = 0.