# ncr in c (combinations)

Tags: c++, c, binomial-coefficients

I m trying to calculate ncr(combinations) in c using dp. But it is failing with n=70. Can anyone help?

```
unsigned long long ncr( int n , int r)
{
unsigned long long c[1001];
int i=1; 
c[0]=1;
for(i=1; i<=r; i++)
    c[i]= ((unsigned long long) (c[i-1]) * (unsigned long long)( n-i+1))%(unsigned long long) (1000000007)/ (unsigned long long)(i);
return c[r];
}
```

basic idea is ncr = ((n-r+1)/r)* nc(r-1)

Answer (score 2):

The intermediate product `(unsigned long long) (c[i-1]) * (unsigned long long)( n-i+1)` is a very big number, and is overflowing the 64 bits word.

You may want to use [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignums). I strongly recommend against developing your own bignum functions (e.g. multiplication and division of bignums), because it is a delicate algorithmic subject (you could still get a PhD about that).

I suggest using some existing bignum library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Some languages or implementations (in particular [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) for Common Lisp) offers native bignum operations. But standard C or C++ don't.

Comment: sorry i used the following in actual code (took mod of ans) :c[i]= ((unsigned long long) (c[i-1]) * (unsigned long long)( n-i+1))%(unsigned long long) (1000000007)/ (unsigned long long)(i);

Comment: But you still need to compute C(n,p) in bignums, and then take the modulus of `1000000007`  which is a large prime number (so all digits or bits of C(n,p) are needed to get the modulus). You really cannot avoid bignums in your case....

Comment: @bhavneet To compute `nCr % p`, you mustn't divide by `i`, you have to multiply with its modular inverse. Also [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862881/1011995).

Answer (score -1):

Make the division before the multiplication.
a*b/c = (a/c) *b where the second better for overflow which seems your problem.

Comment: if u mean  c[i]= (((unsigned long long) (c[i-1])/ (unsigned long long)(i) )* (unsigned long long)( n-i+1))%(unsigned long long) (1000000007); its still not working

Comment: I did not debug it, still u need to make it with rec, much better and readable in my opinion. does it pass for values n>=71?

Comment: The final result is an integer, that doesn't mean each intermediate factor in your particular order of building it up is an integer.

Comment: With `long`, `(a*b)/c` may be different than `(a/c)*b`: `(3*2)/2 == 3 ` which is different than `(3/2)*2 == 2`.