# C++: Combination/multiset functions (factorial overflow)

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics, factorial

I must implement a problem that computes combinations and multisets of m elements from a set of n elements.
The formulas for them are the following ones:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that with factorial it is easy to overflow, so basically what solutions can be for this problem?

Since it is a subproblem of a problem in TopCoder, I have following constraints:

1) A program must be written in C++.

2) I cannot load external libraries.

Comment: Rewrite the explicit term for C(n,m). The one you have in your question is generally the most convenient to work with in theory, but when you actually have to compute it there is one that doesn't overflow as quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need to calculate `n!` directly, which may easily get overflowed. Since

```
C(n,m) = C(n-1, m-1) + C(n-1,m)
C(n,0) = C(n,n) =1
```

You can build a table with size `(n+1,m+1)` and use dynamic programming to build up the table in bottom up manner.

Algorithm pseudocode may like the following:

```
for i ← 0 to n do  // fill out the table row wise
      for j = 0 to min(i, m) do
          if j==0 or j==i then C[i, j] ← 1 
          else C[i, j] ← C[i-1, j-1] + C[i-1, j] 
return C[n, m]
```

If you declare `c(n,m)` to be long double and n is not that big, this way should work. Otherwise, you need to define your own BigInteger class to avoid overflow and define how the `+` operator works for BigIntegers, which are usually represented as array of chars or string.

Comment: should it be j in the second for as a condition or am i missing a point?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev sorry, typo, the second loop variable should be j, not i. I updated the code. good catch, thanks!

Comment: ok, thanks, can't believe that i haven't figured out this different approach

Comment: I like those funky little `←` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Factorials are quite big numbers (they don't fit into a 64 bits word). So you need to use [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (arbitrary precision arithmetic) to compute them in full. Consider using [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) for that purpose (or code in a language and implementation, e.g. Common Lisp with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/), which gives them natively)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14787898/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000103/841108) answers to a question very similar to yours.

Comment: so what if i can't use external libraries and must write it in c++? since i was writing it in TopCoder, i have some restrictions

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: TopCoder lets you use C++, Java, C#, and VB at least.  3 of the 4 of those have arbitrary-length integers built into their standard library, if you wanted to go that route.

Comment: since i know only c++, i can't simply change language to solve one question, but i know that they are built, thanks, just for extending my scope of programming i have asked with constraints, for learning new things, you know

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a recursive approach for calculating factorials which might lead to stack overflow, use iterative approach! This could save you overflow even for larger numbers.

Comment: numbers are overflowing, not stack