# How to Calculate (a/b) %c where a,b and c are very large numbers

Tags: math, numbers, division, modulo, integer-division

I have a function
`f(x)=(1^1)*(2^2)*(3^3)*.....(x^x)`
i have to calculate       `(f(x)/(f(x-r)*f(r)))modulo c`
i can calculate f(x) and (f(x-r)*f(r)). 
assume f(x) is a 
and f(x-r)*f(r) is b. 
c is some number that is very larger. ``
so i how can calculate `(a/b)%c`

Comment: In what language? Maybe it has a multi-precision library.

Comment: You can at least cancel all factors from `r+1` thru `x-r`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118137/fast-n-choose-k-mod-p-for-large-n/10118336#10118336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your f(x) is just ᴨ (PI cumulative multiplication) squared

   - it is hard to write it in here so i will deifine g(x0,x1) instead
   - `g(x0,x1)=x0*(x0+1)*(x0+2)*...*x1`
   - so:
   - `f(x)=g(1,x)^2`
2. computing `h(x,r,c)=f(x)/(f(x-r)*f(r))%c`

   - when you rewrite it to g() you get:
   - `h(x,r,c)=((g(1,x)/(g(1,x-r)*g(1,r)))^2)%c`
   - now simplify (and lower magnitude) as much as you can
   - so compute `sqr` as last (no need to have in sub-results)
   - get rid of duplicate therms
   - there are two options get rid of `g(1,x-r)` or `g(1,r)`
   - choose what is better for you I would chose whichever is bigger
   - so if `(x-r>r)` then:
   - `h(x,r,c)=(g(x-r+1,x)/g(1,r)^2)%c`
   - else:
   - `h(x,r,c)=(g(r+1,x)/g(1,x-r)^2)%c`
3. some math tweaks

   - you should compute both therms a,b (from (a/b)%c) parallel
   - when both can be divided by any of first few primes then divide them booth to keep the magnitude low
   - something like::
   - `if ((a&1==0)&&(b&1==0)) { a>>=1; b>>=1; } // dividing by prime = 2 ... this is usually enough
   - but if your magnitudes are very big then may be you should add also some like 3,5,7,...
   - but always measure the performance drop and stop if it drops too much
4. if `x` is big and `r` is small

   - then compute `b` first
   - and while computing `a`
   - in addition to primes check also if the sub-result is divisible also by `b`
   - if it is then divide `a` by `b` and add the result to the final division result
5. some speed boost

   - you can compute partial `a,b`
   - and start testing the divisibility only if booth have magnitudes bigger then some treshold
   - also you can make the computation waiting for each other
   - so if `a>1000000` then wait until the `b` is also so big or whole
   - and do the same also in revers (if `b>100000` ....)
   - the bigger treshold  the better speed but you are limited by your integer implementation
   - if using bigints then you should use treshold smaller then halve the bits of the base number ...

Hope I did not make some silly math mistake...