# How to find Choose(m, n) % P for large inputs?

Tags: c++, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

```
P = (10^9 + 7)
Choose(m, n) = m! / (n! * (m - n)!)
```

I want to calculate the value of `Choose(m, n) mod P` for large `m` and `n`.
How can I do that in C++ ?

Comment: Look up the Gamma function.

Comment: did you look to [this link ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118137/fast-n-choose-k-mod-p-for-large-n)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use as it has a fairly good range without too much intermediate overflow.  However C(n,k) gets big fast, it is O(n^k) after all.

```
size_t N_choose_K(size_t n, size_t k)
{
    size_t numer = 1;
    size_t denom = 1;
    if (k > n - k) {
        k = n - k;
    }
    while (k > 0) {
        numer *= n;
        denom *= k;
        --n; --k;
    }
    return numer / denom;
}
```

EDIT: Assumes you need integral results.  You can move to floating point results and get more range if you need it and can stand to lose the accuracy.

Comment: Because if you look, `p` is 10^9 which is basically the largest 32-bit number. This is probably something Project Euler where numbers will by gigantic anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Still, it fits in 64 bits with some room to spare.  You can use the recursive formula C(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1,k) and reduce all intermediate results (mod P).  It's not going to be fast, but it should compute correctly.

Comment: Well I've implemented a more or less equivalent approach in Java once, and my experience is that it starts failing when `n` is larger than `150` (or something in that order). Mind that a factorial increases very fast. You need to interleave modulo calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that multiplication is closed under *Z<sub>p</sub>* meaning that: *a b mod p = (a mod p) (b mod p) mod p*. Using this theorem, one can calculate *a<sup>b</sup> mod p* effectively (for instance, this [Python implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211649/67579).

Next we can make use of *Euler's theorem* saying: *a<sup>-1</sup> mod p=a<sup>(p-2)</sup> mod p*.

Now that we know these facts, we can come up with an effective solution: first we multiply over all elements in the numerator, this is thus a range from *k+1* (inclusive) to *n*, and since this is a multiplication, we can always perform a modulo:

```
long long numerator(int n, int k, int p) {
    long long l = 1;
    for(int j = k+1; j <= n; j++) {
        l = (l*j)%p;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Now we still need to divide it by *(n-k)!*. We can do this by first calculating *(n-k)! mod p* like we already did in the previous code fragment:

```
long long denominator(int n, int k, int p) {
    long l = 1;
    for(int j = 2; j <= n-k; j++) {
        l = (l*j)%p;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Now in order to divide it, we can use Euler's theorem on the result of `denominator`. Therefore we first implement the `pow` function with modulo:

```
long long pow(long long a, int k, int p) {
    if(k == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    long long r = pow((a*a)%p,k>>0x01,p);
    if((k&0x01) == 0x01) {//odd number
        r = (r*a)%p;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Now we can merge these together like:

```
long long N_choose_K(int n, int k, int p) {
    long long num = numerator(n,k,p);
    long long den = denominator(n,k,p);
    return (num*pow(den,p-2,p))%p;
}
```

So what you basically do is you determine the numerator `num` in *Z<sub>p</sub>*, the value of the denominator `den` in *Z<sub>p</sub>*, and then you use Euler's theorem to find the inverse of the denominator in *Z<sub>p</sub>*, such that you can multiply and perform the last modulo operation. Then you can return it.