# Store Factorial of large Numbers in python array

Tags: python, arrays, math, list-comprehension, factorial

I want to store factorials of numbers in range 1 to 200,000 but as the factorials for larger numbers are very big my program is running out of space. Is there any way I can store them in a array?

My code:

```
factorial_of_numbers = []
factorial_of_numbers = [factorial_of_numbers[-1] for x in range(0, 200001) if not factorial_of_numbers.append(x*factorial_of_numbers[-1] if factorial_of_numbers else 1)]
```

With this approach I am only able to store factorial till 10,000.

Can anyone suggest any other approach or how to store big factorials?

Comment: If you explain what you need the factorials for, someone might see an alternative approach.

Comment: That's a list, not an array

Comment: It really sounds like you need a tutorial on basic number theory, not a way to beat up your computer

Comment: And if you really want to do it, better think of pushing them to a file instead of using heap.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This only took me about a minute to run:

```
>>> factorials = [1]
>>> for _ in range(200000):
...     factorials.append(factorials[-1] * (len(factorials) + 1))
...
>>> factorials[-1]
2840464893194083513077942336...(VERY LONG NUMBER)
```

Comment: I was asking that in regards of this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358372/given-a-rod-of-length-n-you-need-to-cut-it-into-r-pieces-such-that-each-piec

Comment: 1 minute will exceed time limit for this question

Comment: Then think of using `map` ?

Comment: @amanKumarmahore: you don't mention a time limit anywhere in your question.